Wrote a program to separate vowels and consonants from a string. Counter variable is added in an unusual manner
I have written a program in C where the user gives an input string and the program separates the vowels and consonants into different strings and prints the output but the counter variable does not start from zero and increase in an sequential order.
Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void append(char string[] , char letter)
{
    char arr[] = {letter , '\0'};
    strcat(string,arr);
}
void checkcon(char letter,char string[] , int counter)
{
    char consonants[] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
    for (int i=0;i<=20;i++)
    {
        if (letter == consonants[i])
        {
            append(string,letter);
            counter = counter + 1;
            printf("Con : %d\n",counter);
        }
    }
}
void checkvow(char letter,char string[],int counter)
{
    char vowels[] = "aeiou";
    for (int i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        if (letter == vowels[i])
        {
            append(string,letter);
            counter = counter + 1;
            printf("Vow : %d\n",counter);
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    char inp[5000] = {0};
    char vow[5000] = {0};
    char con[5000] = {0};
    int vowno,conno = 0;
    int length;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",&inp);
    for (length = 0; inp[length] != '\0'; ++length)
    {
        inp[length] = tolower(inp[length]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<=length;i++)
    {
        checkcon(inp[i],con,conno);
        checkvow(inp[i],vow,vowno);
    }
    printf("Consonants: %s\n",con);
    printf("Number of consonants: %d\n",conno);
    printf("Vowels: %s\n",vow);
    printf("Number of vowels: %d",vowno);
    return 0;
}

Output :
Enter a string: String
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Vow : 15081
Con : 1
Con : 1
Consonants: strng
Number of consonants: 0
Vowels: i
Number of vowels: 15080

I do not understand why my counter does not start from zero and increase sequentially.
I tried it with all the alphabets and this is the output:
Enter a string: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Vow : 15081
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Vow : 15081
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Vow : 15081
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Vow : 15081
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Vow : 15081
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Con : 1
Consonants: bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
Number of consonants: 0
Vowels: aeiou
Number of vowels: 15080

I had referred to this since I was using a for loop to check for consonants and vowels instead of a function but I still did not get anything right. My question is quite different from this and from this because neither of the questions use a separate function to check for consonants and vowels and neither question have more details on how their counter is not working.
The problem focuses on why the counter was not working, this has been fixed by initialising the variables and assigning the return value of the function to the respective variables(change return type to int and return 'counter' after the loop).

You never initialize vowno...

vowno and length are both uninitialized.  Crank up your compiler warnings.

When you pass a variable to a function (as in foo(var);) whatever the function does to its argument does not change the value of the variable in the calling function. So int var = 42; foo(var); printf("%d\n", var); will always print 42.

And remember C is pass by value. counter = counter + 1; in those checkcon() and checkvow() functions doesn't modify any variable in the caller like you seen to think it will.

int vowno,conno = 0; ==> int vowno = 0,conno = 0; otherwise vowno is not initialized.

Your program has multiple bugs, and it is not suitable to bring a program to Stack Overflow and expect general help with multiple bugs. You should build a program piece-by-piece. Start with reading a string and counting the vowels—not counting the consonants or building separate strings. Get that working. Then add counting the consonants. Then add building a string. In this way, you would encounter one problem, or at least fewer problems, at a time. This would help you understand what is going on…

… If you got stuck, it would also give you a narrower problem to bring to Stack Overflow, so you could ask one specific question about one specific problem.

Tangent to what @EricPostpischil has said: develop in small pieces and test them often. Don't write your whole program and then test it. Test each function as you write it. When you know a function really works you can move on and use it without worrying about bugs piling up.

Yo @nkminion! Oy, my.  Why deny y from thy "aeiou" tally?  '`y' is always a vowel in this commentary.

I apologise for my poor question framing.

The syntax of variable definition is not as you think it is.
int vowno,conno = 0;

Means:
int vowno;     // define, but not initialize
int conno = 0; // define and initialize

If you want to define and initialize both variables in one line:
int vowno = 0, conno = 0;


This only addresses part of the problem. counter = counter + 1; this has no effect because counter is only a copy of the value passed to the function. It is not visible in the caller function.

I changed lines 52 and 53 to this:
conno = checkcon(inp[i],con,conno);
vowno = checkvow(inp[i],vow,vowno);
and now it works, thank you.
